# JQuery Code Not Compatible in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, select

On my website, I have Jquery that functions to open and close a side menubar. In this side menubar, I have a form with a  tag that lets you choose your class. However, only in internet explorer, when you click on this select, it treats it as if your mouse has left the div and therefore the side menubar closes. I assume this has to do with the way that Internet Explorer draws . However, I don't want to make significant changes mainly because it works in all other browsers just fine. How would I put minimal changes into the code in order to have it compatible with Internet Explorer?

You can find the website here:

http://kpassadore.nivitro.com/

Thanks!

HTML for Menu:

```
<div class="menu">


        <div class="form">

            <form action="php/login.php" method="POST" style="margin-top:20px">
                <select name="class">
                  <option value="pick" selected="selected">Click Here to Choose a Class...</option>
                    <option value="sart">Studio Art</option>
                    <option value="artp">Art Portfolio</option>
                    <option value="bsvd">Basic Visual Design</option>
                    <option value="idam">Industrial Design & Modeling</option>
                    <option value="bipd">Bulldog Industries: Print Design</option>
                    <option value="wdim">Web Design & Interactive Media</option>
                    <option value="maan">Media Arts & Animation</option>
                    <option value="desc">Design Certification(s)</option>
                </select><br/>
               <span> Password: </span><input type="password" name="password" placeholder=" Password"><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
           </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="menuButton">

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

    </div>
```

Javascript for Menu:

```
$('.menuButton').click(function(){
    $('.menuButton').stop().animate({left: '20%'});
    $('.menu').animate({width: '20%'});
});
$('.menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.menu').stop().animate({width: '0%'});
    $('.menuButton').animate({left: '0%'});
});
```

EDIT 1:

Thank you for the comments on my post so far, I have tried to fix a few of the requested errors and tried to simplify my code examples. The way my page works is when you click on ".menuButton" it expands ".menu" out from the side, as i'm sure you have figured out. I will look over some of my html and such and see if I can find something that might be causing this error.

Comment: please provide (simplified) code sample

Comment: I'd just like to note that some browsers are more forgiving of bad HTML/CSS than others.   I'm as quick to curse IE as any web developer, but there have been a few times that it revealed a mistake on my part that the other browsers managed to gloss over somehow.

Comment: *"it treats it as if your house has left "* did you mean mouse?

Comment: in FF on mac, the sidebar closes as I hover over the options in the seelct